# Not able to compile a Gradle project with added .java files from a neighboring project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, playframework, sbt

I'm currently working on transitioning an existing project consisting of two modules into Gradle for easier build/testing for CI and to make the project structure independent from IDEs and easier to understand for new employees. For the sake of example, the project contains 2 top-level modules:

```
./ProjectA
  ./build.gradle
  ./src
  ...
./Play2Project
  ./build.sbt
  ./src
  ./src/entities
  ...
```

`ProjectA` uses `/src/entities` from the second project, which is basically a bunch of `JPA @Entity` files.

The second module is a Play2 project and I'd like to leave it to SBT for compatibility reasons between Gradle and SBT. Unfortunately, SBT doesn't allow sourcing files that are not in the project root and thus I wasn't able to extract the `Entities` into a separate module and share it between `ProjectA` and `Play2Project`. Instead, I added `/src/entities` as a fileTree. Here's `ProjectA`'s `build.gradle` file:

ProjectA/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'conf'
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'test'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'test/resources'
        }
    }
}

jar {...}

repositories {...}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "../Play2Project/src/entities", include: "**/*.java")

    // Remote repo dependencies
    ...
}
```

After adding the `/entities` folder all dependencies seemed to be resolved in IntelliJ (which made me jump on my chair). However, I'm still not able to execute any Gradle build task: the error indicates that the `Entity` files were not added to the classpath:

```
Error:(20, 14) java: package entities does not exist
```

P.S. The `Entity` files do contain `package entities;` in their headers, if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Java source files as dependencies does not make sense. Just add the other source directory by calling:

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDir("../Play2Project/src/entities")
```

in addition to the "src" directory that you have already added. You can call the `srcDir` method multiple times so that you have multiple source directories.

Comment: Thanks @ingo, you replied at the same time as I was typing my own answer :)
I'm fairly new to StackOverflow, which of the two answer should I mark as the right one?

Comment: You can of course do whatever you like, but I would only accept my own answer if other answers are wrong or if nobody else replied.

Answer (score 0):

After some extensive search, I finally found the source of the problem. There were actually two of them:

**1)** I erroneously assumed that adding source code to dependencies would be sufficient (*duh*). So, instead of adding the files I depend on to `dependencies`

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "../Play2Project/src/entities", include: "**/*.java")

    // Remote repo dependencies
    ...
}
```

it should've been added to the `sourceSets`, resulting in this:

```
...
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src', "../Play2Project/src/entities"]
        }
    ...
}
...
```

**2)** Even if I was adding `.class` files to dependencies, it seems like `fileTree()` would've given a wrong result and `files()` should've been used instead (see this https://discuss.gradle.org/t/getting-compile-errors-on-classes-which-exist-in-configurations-compile/1790/3).